# Grade finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: android, build, manifest

I have updated Android Studio and got some trouble with my project.

The console gives me the following error message:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Users/Martin/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

My Gradle file looks marked like that and I do not know why..

under Android Studio->Preferences->Schemas and DTDs 
I have added the path

> http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android

to the ignoring list. 
So the red highlighting of the path appeared to be black again but 
the rest of the issues kept being...

My Gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.stack.overflow"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.0.+'
    compile 'com.afollestad:material-dialogs:0.7.5.2'
}
```

What could I else do to fix my AndroidManifest.xml?

[image]

Comment: post your build.gradle

Comment: I have updated my post.

Comment: `compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"`